# How to extract a frame out of a video using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video, frame

I have a video and I want to extract **35**-th frame out of this video.

I want it to be a png image if possible.

I know there are a lot of questions like this, but I could not find a solution that was using frame number.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Use the [`select` filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#select_002c-aselect):

```
ffmpeg -i <input> -vf "select=eq(n\,34)" -vframes 1 out.png
```

counting starts at 0, so 35th = n value of 34.

Comment: On windows with cmd prompt don't use the quotes around `select=[...]`  Good catch with ffmpeg though, I learn something every day :)

Comment: Also for those interested, this produces the exact same frame as using a calculated time with hexagesimal time format. Tested on a 10.1 second uncompressed video with 300 frames (29.97fps). Time seeked was `00:00:01.17`. Though this (the above) method is probably better for encoded formats or samples with high framerates.

Comment: @jiggunjer Use `"` instead of `'` in Windows. Also, 29.97 can be inaccurate. Use 30000/1001.

Comment: @Levan One more thing, it should be 34 in the command, counting starts at 0.

Comment: Is it possible to count backwards from the end and get the last frame, the second to last frame, etc?

Answer (score 17):

Two quick-and-dirty ways:

Use the [FFmpeg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFmpeg) executable with the seek option. You'll need to convert to a time first, e.g. if I want frame 150 and my video is 29.97 FPS the command will be `ffmpeg -ss 00:00:05.01 -i myvideo.avi -frames:v 1 myimage.jpg`. This might be slightly inaccurate. To seek by exact frame you'd need to use the FFmpeg library with [C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B).

Another 'hacky' way is using [VLC media player](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VLC_media_player). Check menu View -> *Advanced controls*. Pause video and click the Frame-by-frame button 34 times.